# wpf virtual keyboard not work during setup

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, setup-project

I am new on WPF application.
I have done small job on WPF. at here, I have one textbox. when user click or tap virtual keyboard come up. everything is working fine on source code. but when I create a setup & try to install **".msi"** file. during setup my application have page where we have to enter password on textbox. when I click on textbox virtual keyboard is not come up. but if I install application and come that page and click textbox virtual keyboard come up.

I am not able to understand, is there configuration on creating setup or some extra code?

Comment: is it possible...when setup is running at that time DLL or references for virtual keyboard is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said much about what you're actually doing, so there is some guesswork here based on your "...during setup my application...".

It sounds like you are running your application (maybe Installer class-based) as a custom action during your MSI setup. If that's what you're doing it's very unreliable. Installer classes usually work fine, but not if they show UI. The install execute sequence is not intended for showing UI - all that data should be entered during the normal UI sequence at the start of the install. UI with message handlers works only in an STA context, and the execute sequence of an MSI install isn't STA, so messages get lost.

In most cases people postpone this kind of thing until the app actually runs, where it's in an interactive user context. A custom action in a Visual Studio setup project being installed for Everyone will run as the local system account, and that causes some strange errors (such as trying to connect to a database that doesn't have SYSTEM as an allowed user, or accessuing the network).

So this is mostly guesswork because you haven't given much detail, but your issue fits the usual behavior of showing forms from a Visual Studio setup using installer classes.